# ajax moving link text outside of the link tags

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax request to load a table with filtered information.

For example:
Select an employee, hit "GO" to only see results for that employee.

The data filters properly.
The PHP shows in the file the ajax loads:

```
echo "<td><a href=\"creditcard.php?type=Edit&cc_id=".$cc_id."\" />Edit</a></td>";
```

After it loads the data, the DOM shows:

```
<td><a href="creditcard.php?type=Edit&cc_id=8"></a>Edit</td>
```

My AJAX call looks like:

```
$('#go').live('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).hide();
        $(".Results").hide();
        $(".loading").html("<p>Loading...</p>");
        var employee = $('.employee').val();
        var cardtype = $('.cardtype').val();
        var startdate = $('.startdate').val();
        var enddate = $('.enddate').val();
        dataString = "ajax_employee="+employee+"&ajax_cardtype="+cardtype+"&ajax_startdate="+startdate+"&ajax_enddate="+enddate;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "includes/creditcardsearch.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(result){
                $('.Results').html(result);
            },
            complete: function() {
                $(".loading").html('');
                $('.Results').fadeIn('slow');
                $("#go").show();
            }
        });
    });
```

Does anybody have any idea why it's doing this?

Comment: Also, avoid using live and use on

Comment: Thanks... I haven't had to look at the docs in a long time and had no idea live was deprecated. Looks like I have a lot of code to go through.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have `a self closing anchor tag`

```
.$cc_id."\" />Edit</a>  
            ^----    Need to remove this Forward Slash
```

Change it to

```
.$cc_id."\" >Edit</a>
```

Because of the `Extra closing tag` , it interprets as the end of the element and pushing the text outside of the `Anchor Tag`

Comment: lol. I suck at life. Thanks for pointing that out. -- Will mark as answer when the timing is allowed.